# Spontaneous Summoner and multiclass

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells, feats

The Spontaneous Summoner feat from *Complete Divine* lets you spontaneously cast  *summon nature ally* as if you were a druid. One of the conditions to get this feat is being able to cast SNA as a normal spell.

It is not extremely clear to me whether this feat applies to all your classes or only to the classes from which you can cast SNA as normal spell, more specifically: can a druid/sorcerer with this feat use his sorcerer slots to spontaneously cast SNA because he meets the feat prerequisites from being a druid even though he can't cast SNA as a sorcerer?

I am inclined to say no because the feat specifies

> You can spontaneously cast summon nature's ally spells **(from your
>   class spell list)**

But to me it looks like a very vague statement and I'm not sure how to interpret it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct, it only allows you to spontaneously cast those *summon nature’s ally* spells that are already on your spell list. Since no *summon nature’s ally* spells are, by default, found on the sorcerer spell list, a druid/sorcerer could take the feat (he meets the prerequisites) but it would do nothing for him (he already has that ability as a druid, and as a sorcerer there are no *summon nature’s ally* spells for him to spontaneously cast).

The same druid/sorcerer could benefit, however, if he also found an effect that added *summon nature’s ally* spells to his sorcerer spell list (but didn’t add them as spells known). For example, if he gains access to the Animal domain, then per *Complete Divine*’s rules for bonus domains, *summon nature’s ally IV* and *summon nature’s ally VIII* would be added to his sorcerer spell list. Normally, he would still have to select them as spells known, but with Spontaneous Summoning that is no longer necessary.

Answer (score 3):

To employ the benefit of the feat Spontaneous Summoner (*Complete Divine* 85), a creature must have the spells *summon nature's ally* on the class's spell list from which the creature wants to spend spell slots to cast a *summon nature's ally* spell.

For example, the typical druid/sorcerer shouldn't take the feat: the druid/sorcerer can already from the druid side cast spontaneously *summon nature's ally* and the sorcerer spell list doesn't include the *summon nature's ally* spells.

The feat is probably supposed to help spirit shamans—from the same book—feel more druidy.